# What's the maximum acceptable latency if using a remote MySQL DB server?

Tags: mysql

Aside from single server optimization, I am making evaluation in splitting up an existing web application to separate WEB and DB servers.

I understand network latency is an important factor when using a remote database server.

Ideally I would place a dedicated DB server in the same DC as the WEB server or even with a private network.

However, if I really need to put it on a different DC, what's the maximum acceptable network latency in order to get a responsive connectivity?

**Update:**

In the end, I want to ask, if I absolutely need to deploy remote database, what's the best practice and things to consider when it comes to choosing the datacenter and infrastructure?

Comment: Acceptable to who? John Doe? You? Your boss? Your customers?

Comment: Acceptable to the end-user such that it won't feel signifiant slower than having MySQL running on a local server with both WEB and DB residing on the same server.  When WEB server send a request to DB Server, then having result returned back to the WEB server, longer than 1 second is considered "not acceptable".  In this case, what network latency should I be aiming for between these two servers is what I would like to figure out when choosing the right hosting providers.

Comment: I think it's quite easy to figure out: subtract your current query response time (which presumably has negligibly small communications latency) from 1 second, divide by two to account for roundtrip, and you will get the maximum acceptable network latency.

Comment: Within the same DC, I'm getting 4.5 ms latency in average with two dedicated servers. Between different DCs, I'm getting 384.1 ms latency in average.  Is 384.1 ms latency going to constitute significant responsive time for end-user experience in a live production environment?  I'm basing on `mtr --report IP` test result summing up all the average figures on each nodes.

Comment: 384 ms is longer than the round trip time you wold expect on an uncongested route from anywhere to... essentially anywhere else... on the planet.  Yikes.

Comment: 384.1 ms latency is going to constitute exactly 768.2 ms of your 1000 ms target response time, if my math is correct. I sure hope you're not going to query more than a single record, by a unique key, at a time, to meet your performance goal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm used to 80ms between coasts in the US.  Beijing to Brazil was something like 250ms last time I looked.  4.5ms seems high for intra-datacenter.

These are times for a single roundtrip.

If you need to make "too many" SQL calls to a remote MySQL server, think about how you can bundle the queries together in a Stored Routine.  That may let you get it down to one, or at least a lot fewer, roundtrip.

Comment: How do you determine network latency? I'm not sure if the method I used was correct. I `ssh` in to server A, issue `mtr --report server-B-ip`, add up the Avg time for all nodes. Intra-datacenter, only two nodes, `3.4ms` and `1.1ms`, and add up to `4.5ms`.  Remote servers (between CA and US), there are 16 hops, add up to `384ms`. Or should I simply look at the `ping` value? Your idea of `Stored Routine` is interesting, never realize it can be done that way. For implementation, does it need to be custom design?  Or I can easily convert existing web app DB queries into such `Stored Routine`?

Comment: `ping`, `tracert`, `tractroute`, other tools.

Comment: Your web app is custom to some extent; this is just changing some of the code.  What language (or 3rd party app) are you using?  I've only done this SP technique with PHP and Perl.

Comment: I did `traceroute www.google.com` the _last_ line (#9) says about 26ms; do not add the numbers.  California to a New York site: line 8: ~88ms.  384 seems unrealistic.

Comment: The language used in the web app is PHP.  Is there more in-depth reading or tutorial about the SP technique?  If doing `traceroute www.google.com`, I'm getting `24ms` on my US server (server-A), *last line #14*. if issue the command on server-A (US server): `traceroute server-B-ip`, CA (Canada) server, I'm getting `39ms`, *last line #16*.  In this case, if I used `server-A` as DB server, and `server-B` as WEB server.  Will cross-country network latency be negligible to the end-user experience?

Comment: As per your suggestion, I might have calculated my network latency wrong.  If using the value from the last line of `traceroute` it makes more sense.

Comment: `traceroute intra-datacenter-ip` gives me `0.6ms` on *last line #2*.

Comment: But where does google.com start from?  Presumably from _its_ server not _yours_?  Cross-country _may_ be noticeable.  I could certainly see it before I folded 100 SQL statements into one Stored Procedure `CALL`.  (There was also a connect and a few statements that I could not fold in.)  Miami to Vancouver might be 100ms; Detroit to Toronto is probably under 5ms.

Answer (score 5):

There is no single correct answer to this question.  The MySQL client/server protocol has no limitations on toleration of round trip time, but responsiveness of your application can be dramatically affected.

Fundamentally, though, you can't look at any number and know intuitively that it will work, without intimate familiarity with your application.

I recently had to migrate a legacy application piecemeal from on-premise to cloud -- database first, then the app tiers.  The round-trip time between the two sites was 23ms.  "Cake," I thought... "23 ms is no problem."

Unfortunately, it *was* a problem, because the original developers had succumbed to one of the [fallacies of distributed computing](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fallacies_of_distributed_computing): "The latency is zero."

It was a 3-tiered app, and investigation of multi-second page loads revealed that every method call to the application tier on each page on the site triggered a *minimum* of 13 round trips to the database.  GetUserAttributes, GetAccountBalance, GetProductListings... you get the idea... so here's a simple page making 39 largely unnecessary database requests and requiring ~750ms just in transit time, instead of just a few.  (Why so many? They historically used two different ORMs and were still setting up both for each method, redundantly calling USE database and SET autocommit, etc.)  This is an extreme example, but on a LAN, this is the kind of thing you get away with, but that causes your performance to be impacted exponentially as RTT increases.

Where you can achieve hundreds of round trips per second on a LAN, that number drops to about 40 with the 23 ms added in.  That could easily be a factor of 10 or more, even though by human reckoning, 23 ms seems very quick.  Even single-digit round-trips can have a counter-intuitively significant impact on performance.

Fortunately, there's a fairly easy way to simulate latency to a MySQL server in an absolutely meaningful way -- by not simulating it, but actually injecting physical latency: configure a transparent TCP proxy in a remote data center.  For example, HAProxy.  Simple sample config:

```
listen mysql
  mode tcp
  bind *:3306
  server mysql-server 203.0.113.1:3306
  timeout tunnel 28800s
```

This overlooks features you'd want to use in a permanent deployment, like health-checks and ACLs, but if you set this up on a test machine in the remote data center, connect to it on port 3306, it would hairpin the connection back to the MySQL server at 203.0.113.1.  HAProxy is payload agnostic in TCP mode, and it's just forwarding packet payload (using `splice` where available, to avoid much time in userspace) so it will contribute no meaningful latency itself (and can handle a surprising amount of traffic on tiny machines).  If your app and db are local and this proxy is remote, this will perfectly model what your application behavior will be like with *double* the round trip time between the two data centers (because app to db, db to app traverses the entire path twice, not once)... the simulation is a worse than worst case scenario.

If this performance proves acceptable, your proposed round trip time is no problem.  If it isn't, you found the problem before it was too late.

Comment: The idea of using HAProxy for testing on the remote server to simulate the production environment is interesting.  Never though of that, I'll consider using it for evaluation purpose.  In the end, I understand query optimization is critical when it comes to performance.  I've updated my original question, let me know if you have more insight or thoughts about it?

Comment: Query optimization is arguably not *more* important with a distant server -- it's always important -- but everything you can do to minimize response time will help.  I suspect the `best practice and things to consider` aspect of the question is taking the question into off-topic/too broad territory. A remote server means more opportunities for things to break -- network connectivity issues, for example, which many applications may not handle well because they've rarely been an issue. Test your setup to ensure it's viable.

Comment: Can haproxy pause the servers which has high latency ? Due to intermittent issue between haproxy and mysql.